# Is it possible to limit traffic received by a xen domU?

Tags: networking, xen, qos

I have ubuntu 12.04 and openvswitch and xen installed, and I know that limit traffic sent by xen domU can be using rate limit by xen netback or "ingress_policing" by openvswitch.

but because downloading some thing in the xen domUs may consume all of our bandwidth, it there a way to limit traffic receive by xen domUs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally we use this the limit incoming traffic to vm, it takes effect while vm user are downloading data from outside:

```
ovs-vsctl -- set port vps2 qos=@newqos -- --id=@newqos create qos type=linux-htb other-config:max-rate=5000000 queues=0=@q0 \
-- --id=@q0 create queue other-config:max-rate=5000000
```

and the ingress_policing will take effect with the traffic coming out from the vm:

```
ovs-vsctl set interface vps2 ingress_policing_rate=10000
ovs-vsctl set interface vps2 ingress_policing_burst=100
```